# Why can't I rename the iml file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to copy and paste a new moudle.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ1bv.png)

when I rename *.iml file in new moudle,iml file'name of the moudle copied will be changed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vIwf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj8Qi.png)

How to make the iml names of the two modules different?

Answer (score 0):

You must not touch the `.iml` files.

Create a new directory and [add it as another module into the same project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#add-new-module).